# Combinatorial interpretation of an alternating binomial sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $n$ be a fixed natural number. I have reason to believe that $$\sum_{i=k}^n (-1)^{i-k} \binom{i}{k} \binom{n+1}{i+1}=1$$ for all $0\leq k \leq n.$ However I can not prove this. Any method to prove this will be appreciated but a combinatorial solution is greatly preferred. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rewrite the identity with the index of summation changed from $i$ to $j$ where $j=i-k+1$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1-k}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n+1}{k+j}\binom{k+j-1}k=1.$$
Define a "good word" to be a word of length $n+1$ over the alphabet $\{A,B,C\}$ satisfying the conditions: there are exactly $k$ $C$'s, there is at least one $B$, and the first $B$ precedes all the $C$'s.

If $j$ is the number of $B$'s in a good word, then we must have $1\le j\le n+1-k$; moreover, the number of good words with exactly $j$ $B$'s is given by the expression
$$\binom{n+1}{k+j}\binom{k+j-1}k.$$
The combinatorial meaning of the identity is that the number of good words with an odd number of $B$'s is one more than the number of good words with an even number of $B$'s. Here is a bijective proof of that fact.

Let $w$ be the word consisting of a single $B$ preceded by $n-k$ $A$'s and followed by $k$ $C$'s; this is a good word with an odd number of $B$'s. Let $W$ be the set of all good words different from $w$; we have to show that $W$ contains just as many words with an odd as with an even number of $B$'s. To see this, observe that the operation of switching the last non-$C$ letter in a word (from $A$ to $B$ or from $B$ to $A$) is an involution on $W$ which changes the parity of the number of $B$'s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was exactly the type of thing I was looking for!

Comment: Could you provide some insight as to where the definition of good word comes from?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't yet come up with a combinatorial proof, but a proof using induction and the binomial formula is straightforward enough.

We fix $k \geqslant 0$ and use induction on $n \geqslant k$. The base case $n = k$ is simply

$$\sum_{i=k}^k (-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{k+1}{i+1} = (-1)^0 \binom{k}{k}\binom{k+1}{k+1} = 1.$$

For the induction step, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=k}^{n+1} (-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+2}{i+1} &= \sum_{i=k}^{n+1} (-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\left\lbrace \binom{n+1}{i+1} + \binom{n+1}{i}\right\rbrace\\
&=\sum_{i=k}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+1}{i+1} + \sum_{i=k}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+1}{i}\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{i=k}^{n}(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+1}{i+1}}_1 + \underbrace{\sum_{i=k}^{n+1}(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+1}{i}}_{m(k,n)}
\end{align}$$

where in the first sum on the right the term for $i = n+1$ vanishes since $\binom{n+1}{n+1+1} = 0$ and the remainder is the sum for $n$, which is $1$ by the induction hypothesis.

It remains to see that $m(k,n) = 0$. But that is the coefficient of $x^k$ in

$$\begin{align}
x^{n+1} &= \bigl(1 - (1-x)\bigr)^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i}(1-x)^i\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^i (-1)^{i+k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+1}{i}x^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\sum_{i=k}^{n+1}(-1)^{i+k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n+1}{i}\right)x^k,
\end{align}$$

since $(-1)^{i+k} = (-1)^{i-k}$. We have $k \leqslant n < n+1$, hence the coefficient is $0$.

Answer (score 6):

This is a combinatorial  proof of 
$$\sum_{i=k}^n (-1)^{i-k} \binom{i}{k} \binom{n+1}{i+1}=1$$ 
It can be rearranged to 
$$\sum_{i=k+2t } \binom{i}{k} \binom{n+1}{i+1} = 1+ \sum_{i=k+1+2t} \binom{i}{k} \binom{n+1}{i+1} $$

I prefer to talk about 
*choosing $i$ elements from a set whith  $n$ elements* 
to 
*choosing $i+1$ elements from a set with  $n+1$ elements* 
so I substitute $i$ by $i-1$, $k$ by $k-1$ and $n$ by $n-1$ and get
$$\sum_{i=k+2t } \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{n}{i} = 1+ \sum_{i=k+1+2t} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{n}{i} \tag{1} $$

One well known interpretation of $\binom{n}{i}$ is 
as the number of subsets with $i$ elements of the set  $ \{1,2,\ldots,n \}$.

if  $n=9$ then $\{2,3,4,6,8\}$ is a subset with  $i=5$ elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. 
Note that in the notation of  the subsequence we find $i-1=4$ commas (","). 
Let's select two of this commas an replace them by  "} {".
We get $\big\{\{2\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{6,8\}\big\}$ if we replace the  first and the third comma. 
So $\binom{i-1}{k-1}$ can be interpreted as the number of the ways 
a set  with $i$ elements can be splitted into $k$ nonempty subsets $ A_r$ such that 
for each pair A, B of such subsets the following holds: 
$$(a \lt b, \;\; \forall a \in A, \forall b \in B) \;\;\text{or} \;\; (a \gt b, \;\; \forall a \in A, \forall b \in B)$$

The product $\binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{n}{i}$ can be interpreted as the number of ways we can find $k$ 
subsets $A_j$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n \}$ such that
$$ A_r \cap A_s = \emptyset, \forall 1 \le r \lt s \le k \tag{2a}$$
$$ a_r \lt a_s, \forall a_r \in A_r, \forall a_s \in A_s,  1 \le r \lt s \le k \tag{2b}$$
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{k}|A_r|=i \tag{2c}$$

We call the set of all $\{A_1,\ldots \}$ that satisfy $(2)$ as $\Omega_{n,k,i}$. 
We have already seen that 
$$|\Omega_{n,k,i}|=\binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{n}{i} \tag{3}$$
Because of $(2c)$
$$\Omega_{n,k,i} \cap \Omega_{n,k,j} = \emptyset, \; \; \forall i \ne j \tag{4}$$

We define 
$$\Omega_{n,k}'' = \cup_{i=k+2t , i \le n,t \in \mathbb{N_0}}  \Omega_{n,k,i}$$
and
$$\Omega_{n,k}' = \cup_{i=k+1+2t , i \le n,t \in \mathbb{N_0}}  \Omega_{n,k,i}$$
and
$$\Omega_{n,k} = \cup_{i=k}^{n}  \Omega_{n,k,i}= \Omega_{n,k}'' \cup \Omega_{n,k}'$$

It follows from $(4)$ and $(3)$  that
$$|\Omega_{n,k}''| = \sum_{i=k+2t , i \le n,t \in \mathbb{N_0}} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{n}{i}$$
an
$$|\Omega_{n,k}'| = \sum_{i=k+1+2t , i \le n,t \in \mathbb{N_0}} \binom{i-1}{k-1} \binom{n}{i}$$

So to prove $(1)$ we have to show that there is a bijection $\phi$ from 
$\Omega_{n,k}'' \backslash \{\text{one element}\}$ to $\Omega_{n,k}'$.
Let $\omega=\{A_1,\ldots, A_k\}$ an element from $\Omega_{n,k}$.

- If $n \notin A_k$ we define $\phi(\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-1}, A_k\})=\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-1}, A_k \cup \{n\} \}$
- If $n \in A_k$ and $ A_k \ne \{n\}$ we define $\phi(\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-1}, A_k\})=\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-1}, A_k \backslash \{n\} \}$

$\phi$ defined so far is a bijection from $\Omega_{n,k}'' \backslash \Theta_k $ to $\Omega_{n,k}' \backslash \Theta_k  $. $\Theta_k  $ is
$\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-1}, \{n\} \}$

But if  $\omega \in \Theta_n$   there is a problem. 
$A_k \backslash \{n\}= \emptyset$ and  $\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-1}, \emptyset \} $ is not in $\Omega_{n,k}$. 
How can we extend $\phi$ to $\Theta_k$?

Recursively!

- If $n-1 \notin A_{k-1}$ we define $\phi(\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-2}, A_{k-1}, \{n\} \})=\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-2}, A_{k-1}\cup \{n-1\}, \{n\}  \}$
- If $n-1 \in A_{k-1}$ and $ A_{k-1} \ne \{n-1\}$ we define $\phi(\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-2}, A_{k-1}, \{n\} \})=\{A_1,\ldots, A_{k-2} , A_{k-1}  \backslash \{n-1\} , \{n\} \}$

Now we have extended $\phi$ to $\Theta_n \backslash \Theta_{n-1}$. This process can be continued. 
Finally we arrive at the following definition for $\phi$:

For $\{A_1,\ldots,  A_r\},  \;A_j \ne \{n-j\}, \;  A_{r-t}=\{n-t\}, t=0,\ldots,j-1$ we define

- $\phi(\{A_1,\ldots,  A_r\})=\{A_1,\ldots, A_{j-1},A_j \cup \{n-j\},\{n-j+1\},\ldots,\{n\}\}$ if $\{n-j\} \notin A_j $
- $\phi(\{A_1,\ldots,  A_r\})=\{A_1,\ldots, A_{j-1},A_j \backslash \{n-j\},\{n-j+1\},\ldots,\{n\}\}$ if $\{n-j\} \in A_j $

$\phi$ is not defined for  $\{\{n-k+1\},\ldots,\{n\}\}$ 
but it is a bijection from $\Omega_{n,k}'' \backslash \{\{n-k+1\},\ldots,\{n\}\}$ to $\Omega_{n,k}'$. Therefore $(1)$ holds.

**an example**

For $n=5$, $k=3$ we get the following mapping $\phi$

$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
\hline{} \\
\omega & \phi(\omega) \\
\hline{} \\
\Omega_{5,3,3} \subset \Omega_{5,3}'' & \subset \Omega_{5,3}' \\
\hline{} \\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3,5\}\\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{4\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{4,5\}\\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{2,4\}\;\{5\}\\
\{1\}\;\{3\}\;\{4\} & \{1\}\;\{3\}\;\{4,5\}\\
\{1\}\;\{3\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{5\}\\
\{1\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} & \{1,3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\}\\
\{2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4\} & \{2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4,5\}\\
\{2\}\;\{3\}\;\{5\} & \{2\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{5\}\\
\{2\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} & \{2,3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\}\\
\{3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} &  \text{no image} \\ 
\hline{} \\
\Omega_{5,3,4} \subset \Omega_{5,3}' & \subset \Omega_{5,3}'' \\ 
\hline{} \\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3,4\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3,4,5\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{4\} & \{1\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{4,5\} \\
\{1,2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4\} & \{1,2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4,5\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3,5\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{2,3,4\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1,2\}\;\{3\}\;\{5\} & \{1,2\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{4,5\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{4\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2,4\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1,2\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} & \{1,2,3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1\}\;\{3\}\;\{4,5\} & \{1\}\;\{3\}\;\{4\} \\
\{1\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{3\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1,3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} \\
\{2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4,5\} & \{2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4\} \\
\{2\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{5\} & \{2\}\;\{3\}\;\{5\} \\
\{2,3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} & \{2\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} \\
\hline{} \\
\Omega_{5,3,5} \subset \Omega_{5,3}'' &  \subset \Omega_{5,3}' \\
\hline{} \\
\{1,2,3\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} & \{1,2\}\;\{4\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1,2\}\;\{3,4\}\;\{5\} & \{1,2\}\;\{3\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1,2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4,5\} & \{1,2\}\;\{3\}\;\{4\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2,3,4\}\;\{5\} & \{1\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{5\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{4,5\} & \{1\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{4\} \\
\{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3,4,5\} & \{1\}\;\{2\}\;\{3,4\} \\
\hline{}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Nice proof. A small typo: If I understood it correctly, the first row in your table should be mapped to $\{1\}\{2\}\{3,5\}$ instead of $\{1\}\{2\}\{3,4\}$.

Comment: Your are right, thank you, i will change this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another algebraic proof. Observe that when we multiply two exponential generating functions of the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that
$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} \sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
i.e. the product of the two generating functions is the generating function of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

The sum we are trying to evaluate is
$$\sum_{k=j}^n (-1)^{k-j} {k\choose j} {n+1\choose k+1} =
(n+1)  \sum_{k=j}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-j}}{k+1} {k\choose j} {n\choose k}.$$
Now let $$A_1(z)
= \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{k-j} {k\choose j} \frac{z^k}{k!} =
\frac{1}{j!} \sum_{k\ge j} (-1)^{k-j}  \frac{z^k}{(k-j)!}
\\= \frac{1}{j!} z^j \sum_{k\ge j} (-1)^{k-j}  \frac{z^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}
= \frac{1}{j!} z^j \exp(-z).$$
It then follows that
$$ A(z) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} {k\choose j} \frac{z^k}{k!}
= \frac{1}{z} \left(C + \int A_1(z) dz\right)$$
with $C$ a constant to be determined.

Now it is not difficult to show (consult the end of this post) that 
$$\int A_1(z) dz = -\exp(-z)  \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!}$$
and we must have 
$$C = -[z^0] \left(-\exp(-z)  \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!} \right)= 1$$
so that
$$A(z) =  \frac{1}{z} \left(1 -\exp(-z)  \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$
We have now determined $A(z)$ for the convolution of the two generating functions.

We take $$B(z) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{z^k}{k!} = \exp(z).$$
It follows that
$$A(z) B(z) =
\frac{1}{z} \left(\exp(z) -  \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$
Now applying the coefficient extraction operator we get for $n\ge j$ that
$$(n+1)  n! [z^n] A(z) B(z) =
(n+1)!  [z^{n+1}] \left(\exp(z) -  \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$
None of the terms from the sum contribute because $n+1>j$ so that we are left with
$$(n+1)! [z^{n+1}] \exp(z) = (n+1)!  \frac{1}{(n+1)!} = 1.$$

**Verification.**
$$\left(-\exp(-z)  \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)' =
\exp(-z)   \sum_{q=0}^j \frac{z^q}{q!} - \exp(-z)  \sum_{q=0}^{j-1} \frac{z^q}{q!}
= \exp(-z) \frac{z^j}{j!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha yields this result:

[image]

It's [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%20=%20k%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%28-1%29%5E%7Bi%20-%20k%7D%7Bi%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%7Bn%20%2b%201%20%5Cchoose%20i%20%2b%201%7D) !!!

It's too bad for Wolfram Alpha that ${\bf they\ don't\ say}$ that the right hand side is identical to $\color{#0000ff}{\large\mbox{ONE}\ = 1}$.

Comment: The assumptions that $k,n$ are positive integers goes a long way to simplify this. It's indeed just 1.

Comment: @AlexR. It's true. But if I got a result likes $1.35$, I don't write, for example $\displaystyle{\large{2.7 \over 2}\,{\sqrt{2\,}\,\sqrt{3\,} \over \sqrt{6\,}}}$. I write a plain $\large 1.35$.

Comment: It does, if you use the *FunctionExpand[...]* command.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we  seek to verify that
$$\sum_{q=k}^n (-1)^{q-k} {q\choose k} {n+1\choose q+1} = 1$$
where $n\ge k.$

We first treat the case when $k\gt 0$ and introduce
$${q\choose k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^q \; dz.$$

Observe that this is zero when $0\le q\lt k$ so that we may extend the
limit in the sum to zero, getting
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^{q-k} {n+1\choose q+1} (1+z)^q
\; dz
\\ = (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1+z}
\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^{q+1} {n+1\choose q+1} (1+z)^{q+1}
\; dz
\\ = (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1+z}
\sum_{q=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{q} {n+1\choose q} (1+z)^{q}
\; dz
\\ = (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1+z}
(-1+(1-(1+z))^{n+1})
\; dz
\\ = (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1+z}
(-1 + (-1)^{n+1} z^{n+1})
\; dz.$$

Now since $n\ge k$ this simplifies to
$$(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1+z} \; dz
= (-1)^k (-1)^k = 1.$$

The second case when $k=0$ yields
$$\sum_{q=0}^n (-1)^{q} {n+1\choose q+1} 
= - \sum_{q=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{q} {n+1\choose q}
= - ((1-1)^{n+1}-1) = 1.$$