# Summation of Alternating Products in Pascal's Triangle: prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} x_{k} y_{n-k+1} = 1$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Dappy is playing around with Pascal's Triangle. While looking for patterns, he finds one equality that he likes a lot:

Pick any spot on Pascal's Triangle that isn't part of the right edge. Call the elements which are to the right of this spot on the same row $x_{k}$, such that $x_{1}$ denotes the position right next to the picked spot, and $x_{n}$ denotes the rightmost element on the row (which would be part of the right edge).

Similarly, denote by $y_{k}$ the elements going in the upwards-right direction.

Help Dappy prove that

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} x_{k} y_{n-k+1} = 1.$

[image]

Comment: Dappy should read the tag descriptions when asking questions at MSE: the algebraic-geometry tag is "should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry" and the number-theory tag is for "[q]uestions on advanced topics - beyond those in typical introductory courses".

Comment: I would suggest that you try to write $x_k$ and $y_{n-k+1}$ in terms of the binomial coefficients, and then do a [search on Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/). The chances are high that this has been asked and answered  before.

Comment: I didn't get anything

Comment: I am fairly sure that it is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/503694/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

For some $m\ge 1$, $0\le l\le m-1$,
$$
x_k=\binom{m}{k+l}, \ \ y_r=\binom{m-r}{l},\ \ n=m-l
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{1\le k\le n} (-1)^{k+1} x_{k} y_{n-k+1} \\
&=&\sum_{1\le k\le m-l} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{m}{k+l} \binom{l+k-1}{l}\\
&=&\sum_{1\le k\le m-l} \binom{m}{m-(k+l)} \binom{-l-1}{k-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
since
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{l+k-1}{l}&=&\binom{l+k-1}{k-1}\\
&=&\frac{(l+k-1)\cdots(l+1)}{(k-1)!}\\
&=&(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(-l-1)\cdots(-l-(k-1))}{(k-1)!}\\
&=&(-1)^{k-1}\binom{-l-1}{k-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So, since $\binom{m}{m-(k+l)}$ is the coefficient of $x^{m-(k+l)}$ in $(1+x)^m$ and $\binom{-l-1}{k-1}$ is the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ in $(1+x)^{-l-1}$, the sum is the coefficient of $x^{m-l-1}$ in
$$
(1+x)^m\cdot (1+x)^{-l-1} = (1+x)^{m-l-1},
$$
which is 1.

Comment: This is a great solution I am eager to know what are the other approaches for this question if you have any other solution please upload them

Comment: As Martin R commented above, this is the same problem as [post #503694](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503694/combinatorial-interpretation-of-an-alternating-binomial-sum), so you can enjoy the solutions there.